# Roughly equivalent code of partial

Tags: python

In the official docs [10.2. functools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html)
 about partial

Roughly equivalent to:

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

I guess it could be better if refactor it as:

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        return func(*args, *fargs, **fkeywords, **keywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

or

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newargs = args.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        args.append(fargs)
        return func(*args, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

Does my assumption make sense?

Comment: Have you tried either of those? Your first rewrite will fail if `fkeywords` and `keywords` share the same parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first version doesn't quite work, because, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) explain:

> If additional keyword arguments are supplied, they extend and override keywords.

When you do two keyword splats, as in your version, you don't override duplicated keywords; instead, you get a `TypeError`, as explained in [`Calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax **expression appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to a mapping, the contents of which are treated as additional keyword arguments. If a keyword is already present (as an explicit keyword argument, or from another unpacking), a TypeError exception is raised.

Compare:

```
>>> def sub(a, b): return a-b
>>> sub2 = functools.partial(sub, b=2)
>>> sub2(5, b=0)
5
>>> sub2 = partial(sub, b=2)
>>> sub2(5, b=0)
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'b'
```

---

Your second version doesn't work for four reasons:

- `*args` is a tuple, and tuples don't have `copy`. Being immutable, there's rarely a reason to copy them.
- Tuples also don't have `append`, being immutable.
- Even if they were lists, `append` would add the new argument list as a single argument to the end, but you want to add them all as separate arguments. That's what `extend` is for.
- Finally, you used `args` instead of `newargs`.

You could fix all of that by doing something like this:

```
def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
    newkeywords = keywords.copy()
    newargs = list(args)
    newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
    newargs.extend(fargs)
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywords)
```

But a simpler (and more efficient) way to write that would be:

```
def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
    newkeywords = keywords.copy()
    newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
    newargs = args + fargs
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywords)
```

And this is in fact pretty close to how `partial` used to be documented before Python allowed multiple splats in a single call in 3.5. In both [3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and [2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
    newkeywords = keywords.copy()
    newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
    return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
```

The only difference is they do the `args + fargs` directly in the splat, instead of assigning it to a `newargs` variable.

Comment: ty. The extended topic about `allowed multiple splats`  seem complicated

Comment: What's the splat mean here? I google multiple splats return nothing useful.

Comment: @john Sorry, "splat" is the informal term for using `*` (or `**`) to pass a sequence (or mapping) to be unpacked into multiple positional (or keyword) arguments. The formal term for "splat" is "use the iterable-unpacking syntax". If you google "allowed multiple splats _python_" you get much better results. (Including [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), the proposal to allow multiple uses of `*` in function calls starting in Python 3.5.)